# How can I install JBoss EAP and JBoss EWS Support in OpenShift Origin

Tags: openshift-origin

I created a VM with OpenShift Origin in CentOS 6.5 which followed the oo-installer guide. However, when I follow the [Install JBoss EAP and JBoss EWS Support](http://openshift.github.io/documentation/oo_administration_guide.html#install-jboss-eap-and-jboss-ews-support) to install JBoss EAP cartridge, I got dependency error which requires several dependencies, like jbossas-domain, maven3... as following... How can I fix this?

> yum install openshift-origin-cartridge-jbosseap.noarch openshif
> t-origin-cartridge-jbossews.noarch
> openshift-origin-cartridge-jenkins.noarch ope
> nshift-origin-cartridge-jenkins-client.noarch
>
> Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, versionlock Repository
> 'jenkins-repo' is missing name in configuration, using id Repository
> 'openshift-deps' is missing name in configuration, using id Repository
> 'openshift-optional' is missing name in configuration, using id
> Repository 'openshift-origin' is missing name in configuration, using
> id Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile  * base:
> centos.mirror.serversaustralia.com.au  * extras:
> centos.mirror.crucial.com.au  * updates: centos.mirror.crucial.com.au
> 349 packages excluded due to repository priority protections Setting
> up Install Process Package
> openshift-origin-cartridge-jenkins-1.23.1.1-1.el6.noarch already
> install
> ed and latest version Package
> openshift-origin-cartridge-jenkins-client-1.22.4.1-1.el6.noarch
> already
> installed and latest version Resolving Dependencies
> --> Running transaction check
> ---> Package openshift-origin-cartridge-jbosseap.noarch 0:2.19.1.1-1.el6 will be
> installed
> --> Processing Dependency: maven3 for package: openshift-origin-cartridge-jbosse
> ap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-welcome-content-eap for package: openshift-or
> igin-cartridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-standalone for package: openshift-origin-cart
> ridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-product-eap for package: openshift-origin-car
> tridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-modules-eap for package: openshift-origin-car
> tridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-jbossweb-native for package: openshift-origin
> -cartridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-hornetq-native for package: openshift-origin-
> cartridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-domain for package: openshift-origin-cartridg
> e-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-core for package: openshift-origin-cartridge-
> jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-bundles for package: openshift-origin-cartrid
> ge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-appclient for package: openshift-origin-cartr
> idge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jboss-openshift-metrics-module for package: openshift
> -origin-cartridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jboss-eap6-modules for package: openshift-origin-cart
> ridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jboss-eap6-index for package: openshift-origin-cartri
> dge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel for package: openshift-origi
> n-cartridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: bc for package: openshift-origin-cartridge-jbosseap-2
> .19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> ---> Package openshift-origin-cartridge-jbossews.noarch 0:1.25.3.1-1.el6 will be
> installed
> --> Processing Dependency: tomcat7 for package: openshift-origin-cartridge-jboss
> ews-1.25.3.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: tomcat6 for package: openshift-origin-cartridge-jboss
> ews-1.25.3.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: maven3 for package: openshift-origin-cartridge-jbosse
> ws-1.25.3.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Running transaction check
> ---> Package bc.x86_64 0:1.06.95-1.el6 will be installed
> ---> Package java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64 1:1.7.0.65-2.5.1.2.el6_5 will be in
> stalled
> ---> Package jboss-openshift-metrics-module.noarch 0:1.0.2.redhat_1-1.2.el6oso w
> ill be installed
> --> Processing Dependency: quartz for package: jboss-openshift-metrics-module-1.
> 0.2.redhat_1-1.2.el6oso.noarch
> ---> Package openshift-origin-cartridge-jbosseap.noarch 0:2.19.1.1-1.el6 will be
> installed
> --> Processing Dependency: maven3 for package: openshift-origin-cartridge-jbosse
> ap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-welcome-content-eap for package: openshift-or
> igin-cartridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-standalone for package: openshift-origin-cart
> ridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-product-eap for package: openshift-origin-car
> tridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-modules-eap for package: openshift-origin-car
> tridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-jbossweb-native for package: openshift-origin
> -cartridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-hornetq-native for package: openshift-origin-
> cartridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-domain for package: openshift-origin-cartridg
> e-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-core for package: openshift-origin-cartridge-
> jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-bundles for package: openshift-origin-cartrid
> ge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-appclient for package: openshift-origin-cartr
> idge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jboss-eap6-modules for package: openshift-origin-cart
> ridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jboss-eap6-index for package: openshift-origin-cartri
> dge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> ---> Package openshift-origin-cartridge-jbossews.noarch 0:1.25.3.1-1.el6 will be
> installed
> --> Processing Dependency: tomcat7 for package: openshift-origin-cartridge-jboss
> ews-1.25.3.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: maven3 for package: openshift-origin-cartridge-jbosse
> ws-1.25.3.1-1.el6.noarch
> ---> Package tomcat6.noarch 0:6.0.24-78.el6_5 will be installed
> --> Processing Dependency: tomcat6-lib = 6.0.24-78.el6_5 for package: tomcat6-6.
> 0.24-78.el6_5.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jakarta-commons-pool for package: tomcat6-6.0.24-78.e
> l6_5.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jakarta-commons-dbcp for package: tomcat6-6.0.24-78.e
> l6_5.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jakarta-commons-daemon for package: tomcat6-6.0.24-78
> .el6_5.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jakarta-commons-collections for package: tomcat6-6.0.
> 24-78.el6_5.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: /lib/lsb/init-functions for package: tomcat6-6.0.24-7
> 8.el6_5.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: /lib/lsb/init-functions for package: tomcat6-6.0.24-7
> 8.el6_5.noarch
> --> Running transaction check
> ---> Package jakarta-commons-collections.noarch 0:3.2.1-3.4.el6 will be installe
> d
> ---> Package jakarta-commons-daemon.x86_64 1:1.0.1-8.9.el6 will be installed
> ---> Package jakarta-commons-dbcp.noarch 0:1.2.1-13.8.el6 will be installed
> ---> Package jakarta-commons-pool.x86_64 0:1.3-12.7.el6 will be installed
> ---> Package openshift-origin-cartridge-jbosseap.noarch 0:2.19.1.1-1.el6 will be
> installed
> --> Processing Dependency: maven3 for package: openshift-origin-cartridge-jbosse
> ap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-welcome-content-eap for package: openshift-or
> igin-cartridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-standalone for package: openshift-origin-cart
> ridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-product-eap for package: openshift-origin-car
> tridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-modules-eap for package: openshift-origin-car
> tridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-jbossweb-native for package: openshift-origin
> -cartridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-hornetq-native for package: openshift-origin-
> cartridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-domain for package: openshift-origin-cartridg
> e-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-core for package: openshift-origin-cartridge-
> jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-bundles for package: openshift-origin-cartrid
> ge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-appclient for package: openshift-origin-cartr
> idge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jboss-eap6-modules for package: openshift-origin-cart
> ridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jboss-eap6-index for package: openshift-origin-cartri
> dge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> ---> Package openshift-origin-cartridge-jbossews.noarch 0:1.25.3.1-1.el6 will be
> installed
> --> Processing Dependency: tomcat7 for package: openshift-origin-cartridge-jboss
> ews-1.25.3.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: maven3 for package: openshift-origin-cartridge-jbosse
> ws-1.25.3.1-1.el6.noarch
> ---> Package quartz.noarch 0:2.2.1.redhat_1-1.el6oso will be installed
> ---> Package redhat-lsb-core.x86_64 0:4.0-7.el6.centos will be installed
> --> Processing Dependency: perl-CGI for package: redhat-lsb-core-4.0-7.el6.cento
> s.x86_64
> --> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/time for package: redhat-lsb-core-4.0-7.el6.
> centos.x86_64
> --> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/pax for package: redhat-lsb-core-4.0-7.el6.c
> entos.x86_64
> --> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/msgfmt for package: redhat-lsb-core-4.0-7.el
> 6.centos.x86_64
> --> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/man for package: redhat-lsb-core-4.0-7.el6.c
> entos.x86_64
> --> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/batch for package: redhat-lsb-core-4.0-7.el6
> .centos.x86_64
> --> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/at for package: redhat-lsb-core-4.0-7.el6.ce
> ntos.x86_64
> --> Processing Dependency: /bin/mailx for package: redhat-lsb-core-4.0-7.el6.cen
> tos.x86_64
> --> Processing Dependency: /bin/gettext for package: redhat-lsb-core-4.0-7.el6.c
> entos.x86_64
> --> Processing Dependency: /bin/ed for package: redhat-lsb-core-4.0-7.el6.centos
> .x86_64
> ---> Package tomcat6-lib.noarch 0:6.0.24-78.el6_5 will be installed
> --> Processing Dependency: tomcat6-servlet-2.5-api = 6.0.24-78.el6_5 for package
> : tomcat6-lib-6.0.24-78.el6_5.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: tomcat6-jsp-2.1-api = 6.0.24-78.el6_5 for package: to
> mcat6-lib-6.0.24-78.el6_5.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: tomcat6-el-2.1-api = 6.0.24-78.el6_5 for package: tom
> cat6-lib-6.0.24-78.el6_5.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: ecj for package: tomcat6-lib-6.0.24-78.el6_5.noarch
> --> Running transaction check
> ---> Package at.x86_64 0:3.1.10-43.el6_2.1 will be installed
> ---> Package ecj.x86_64 1:3.4.2-6.el6 will be installed
> ---> Package ed.x86_64 0:1.1-3.3.el6 will be installed
> ---> Package gettext.x86_64 0:0.17-16.el6 will be installed
> --> Processing Dependency: cvs for package: gettext-0.17-16.el6.x86_64
> ---> Package mailx.x86_64 0:12.4-7.el6 will be installed
> ---> Package man.x86_64 0:1.6f-32.el6 will be installed
> ---> Package openshift-origin-cartridge-jbosseap.noarch 0:2.19.1.1-1.el6 will be
> installed
> --> Processing Dependency: maven3 for package: openshift-origin-cartridge-jbosse
> ap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-welcome-content-eap for package: openshift-or
> igin-cartridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-standalone for package: openshift-origin-cart
> ridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-product-eap for package: openshift-origin-car
> tridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-modules-eap for package: openshift-origin-car
> tridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-jbossweb-native for package: openshift-origin
> -cartridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-hornetq-native for package: openshift-origin-
> cartridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-domain for package: openshift-origin-cartridg
> e-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-core for package: openshift-origin-cartridge-
> jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-bundles for package: openshift-origin-cartrid
> ge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-appclient for package: openshift-origin-cartr
> idge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jboss-eap6-modules for package: openshift-origin-cart
> ridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jboss-eap6-index for package: openshift-origin-cartri
> dge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> ---> Package openshift-origin-cartridge-jbossews.noarch 0:1.25.3.1-1.el6 will be
> installed
> --> Processing Dependency: tomcat7 for package: openshift-origin-cartridge-jboss
> ews-1.25.3.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: maven3 for package: openshift-origin-cartridge-jbosse
> ws-1.25.3.1-1.el6.noarch
> ---> Package pax.x86_64 0:3.4-10.1.el6 will be installed
> ---> Package perl-CGI.x86_64 0:3.51-136.el6 will be installed
> ---> Package time.x86_64 0:1.7-37.1.el6 will be installed
> ---> Package tomcat6-el-2.1-api.noarch 0:6.0.24-78.el6_5 will be installed
> ---> Package tomcat6-jsp-2.1-api.noarch 0:6.0.24-78.el6_5 will be installed
> ---> Package tomcat6-servlet-2.5-api.noarch 0:6.0.24-78.el6_5 will be installed
> --> Running transaction check
> ---> Package cvs.x86_64 0:1.11.23-16.el6 will be installed
> ---> Package openshift-origin-cartridge-jbosseap.noarch 0:2.19.1.1-1.el6 will be
> installed
> --> Processing Dependency: maven3 for package: openshift-origin-cartridge-jbosse
> ap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-welcome-content-eap for package: openshift-or
> igin-cartridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-standalone for package: openshift-origin-cart
> ridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-product-eap for package: openshift-origin-car
> tridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-modules-eap for package: openshift-origin-car
> tridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-jbossweb-native for package: openshift-origin
> -cartridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-hornetq-native for package: openshift-origin-
> cartridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-domain for package: openshift-origin-cartridg
> e-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-core for package: openshift-origin-cartridge-
> jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-bundles for package: openshift-origin-cartrid
> ge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jbossas-appclient for package: openshift-origin-cartr
> idge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jboss-eap6-modules for package: openshift-origin-cart
> ridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: jboss-eap6-index for package: openshift-origin-cartri
> dge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch
> ---> Package openshift-origin-cartridge-jbossews.noarch 0:1.25.3.1-1.el6 will be
> installed
> --> Processing Dependency: tomcat7 for package: openshift-origin-cartridge-jboss
> ews-1.25.3.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Processing Dependency: maven3 for package: openshift-origin-cartridge-jbosse
> ws-1.25.3.1-1.el6.noarch
> --> Finished Dependency Resolution Error: Package: openshift-origin-cartridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch (opens
> hift-origin)
> Requires: jbossas-domain Error: Package: openshift-origin-cartridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch (opens
> hift-origin)
> Requires: jbossas-jbossweb-native Error: Package: openshift-origin-cartridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch (opens
> hift-origin)
> Requires: jbossas-core Error: Package: openshift-origin-cartridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch (opens
> hift-origin)
> Requires: jbossas-welcome-content-eap Error: Package: openshift-origin-cartridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch (opens
> hift-origin)
> Requires: jbossas-bundles Error: Package: openshift-origin-cartridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch (opens
> hift-origin)
> Requires: jbossas-appclient Error: Package: openshift-origin-cartridge-jbossews-1.25.3.1-1.el6.noarch (opens
> hift-origin)
> Requires: maven3 Error: Package: openshift-origin-cartridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch (opens
> hift-origin)
> Requires: jbossas-product-eap Error: Package: openshift-origin-cartridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch (opens
> hift-origin)
> Requires: jbossas-standalone Error: Package: openshift-origin-cartridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch (opens
> hift-origin)
> Requires: maven3 Error: Package: openshift-origin-cartridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch (opens
> hift-origin)
> Requires: jbossas-modules-eap Error: Package: openshift-origin-cartridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch (opens
> hift-origin)
> Requires: jboss-eap6-modules Error: Package: openshift-origin-cartridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch (opens
> hift-origin)
> Requires: jbossas-hornetq-native Error: Package: openshift-origin-cartridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch (opens
> hift-origin)
> Requires: jboss-eap6-index Error: Package: openshift-origin-cartridge-jbossews-1.25.3.1-1.el6.noarch (opens
> hift-origin)
> Requires: tomcat7
> You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
> You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

Comment: I asked around and this mailing list archive might help clear things up about this issue: http://lists.openshift.redhat.com/openshift-archives/dev/2014-July/msg00175.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JBoss AS and JBoss EWS installation guide for Redhat OpenShift Origin v4

Unfortunately up to now, the JBoss AS and EWS are not officially supported on OpenShift Origin v4, however there is a solution for that.
Thanks for Diego Castro from Getup Cloud (http://getupcloud.com) for creating the necessary RPM packages, it was him who actually enabled the possibility to install JBoss AS on OpenShift Origin v4 for us.

So you have to install the following RPM packages before you can enable the installation of the JBoss cartridges

```
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/getup-mirror/getup-openshift-origin-release-4/dependencies/tomcat6-6.0.39-1.noarch.rpm
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/getup-mirror/getup-openshift-origin-release-4/dependencies/tomcat7-7.0.50-1.noarch.rpm
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/getup-mirror/getup-openshift-origin-release-4/dependencies/maven3-3.0.3-4.noarch.rpm
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/getup-mirror/getup-openshift-origin-release-4/dependencies/jboss-as7-modules-7.1.1.Final-1.noarch.rpm
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/getup-mirror/getup-openshift-origin-release-4/dependencies/jboss-as7-7.1.1.Final-1.noarch.rpm
```

you can probably install them directly, but I prefer downloading them with wget and then running "yum install" on them.

To directly install them all with yum run:

```
yum install -y \
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/getup-mirror/getup-openshift-origin-release-4/dependencies/tomcat6-6.0.39-1.noarch.rpm \
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/getup-mirror/getup-openshift-origin-release-4/dependencies/tomcat7-7.0.50-1.noarch.rpm \
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/getup-mirror/getup-openshift-origin-release-4/dependencies/maven3-3.0.3-4.noarch.rpm \
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/getup-mirror/getup-openshift-origin-release-4/dependencies/jboss-as7-modules-7.1.1.Final-1.noarch.rpm \
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/getup-mirror/getup-openshift-origin-release-4/dependencies/jboss-as7-7.1.1.Final-1.noarch.rpm
```

If the installs were successful, you should be able to install now these OpenShift cartridges, so just run:

```
yum install openshift-origin-cartridge-jbossas
yum install openshift-origin-cartridge-jbossews
```

If you can't install these, maybe try running the installation of packages again.

Now thsese should be successful too. If they are, they will be listed under "Installed", somewhat like this:

```
Installed:
  openshift-origin-cartridge-jbossas.noarch 0:1.26.1.1-1.el6                    

Dependency Installed:
  jboss-openshift-metrics-module.noarch 0:1.0.2.redhat_1-1.2.el6oso             
  quartz.noarch 0:2.2.1.redhat_1-1.el6oso
```

So now after checking the "yum list installed" looked like this:

```
# yum list installed | grep jboss
jboss-as7.noarch                          7.1.1.Final-1        @/jboss-as7-7.1.1.Final-1.noarch
jboss-as7-modules.noarch                  7.1.1.Final-1        @/jboss-as7-modules-7.1.1.Final-1.noarch
jboss-openshift-metrics-module.noarch     1.0.2.redhat_1-1.2.el6oso
openshift-origin-cartridge-jbossas.noarch 1.26.1.1-1.el6       @openshift-origin
openshift-origin-cartridge-jbossews.noarch

# yum list installed | grep tomc
apache-tomcat-apis.noarch                 0.1-1.el6            @base            
tomcat6.noarch                            6.0.39-1             @/tomcat6-6.0.39-1.noarch
tomcat7.noarch                            7.0.50-1             @/tomcat7-7.0.50-1.noarch
```

Now run:

```
service ruby193-mcollective restart
```

Might look something like this:

```
# service ruby193-mcollective restart
Shutting down mcollective:                                 [  OK  ]
Starting mcollective: warn 2014/09/30 04:31:42: config.rb:117:in `block in loadconfig' Use of deprecated 'topicprefix' option.  This option is ignored and should be removed from '/opt/rh/ruby193/root/etc/mcollective/server.cfg'
                                                           [  OK  ]
```

Then run the activation of the cartridges:

```
oo-admin-ctl-cartridge -c import-node --activate
```

The output should now look something like this:

```
# oo-admin-ctl-cartridge -c import-node --activate
warn 2014/09/30 04:33:03: config.rb:117:in `block in loadconfig' Use of deprecated 'topicprefix' option.  This option is ignored and should be removed from '/opt/rh/ruby193/root/etc/mcollective/client.cfg'
Updating 3 cartridges ...
542a6ac5653e8a988b000001 # A jbossas-7 (active)
542a6ac5653e8a988b000002 # A jbossews-2.0 (active)
542a6ac5653e8a988b000003 # A jbossews-1.0 (active)
```

If that didn't work, then maybe try restarting the VM. That might help.

So now those cartridges should be available, you should be able to find them by checking the cartridge list with:

```
rhc cartridge list
```

So between all the cartridges you should now also be able to find these:

```
jbossas-7           JBoss Application Server 7           web
jbossews-1.0        Tomcat 6 (JBoss EWS 1.0)             web
jbossews-2.0        Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0)             web
```

You should now be able to use these cartridges in OpenShift.

Hope this helps you guys!